# Google Cloud Platform Access Context Manager policy does not show in console but I can see it when I use gcloud access-context-manager policies list

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Why does the command `gcloud access-context-manager policies list --organization ORGANIZATION_ID` show my policies, but when I'm in context of that organization in the console, Security to Access Context Manager does not have any listed? I run into issues assuming I can assign one with the same name. Am I looking at the wrong place in the portal for this? https://console.cloud.google.com/security/access-level?organizationId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Bit late the party, but I noticed the same thing.. seems you can see the *Access levels* that the *Access Policy* holds, but not the *Access Policy* itself

https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-access-policy

*The Cloud Console does not currently support managing access policies. If you want to manage your access policy, you must use the gcloud command-line tool or the API*