# How can I delete a GCP access context manager org level policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

In my GCP organization I have a policy by the name `bucket policy` of which I need to get rid. Originally, this policy was managed by Terraform, but my state has since been corrupted.

My dependencies are straightforward enough that I should be able to safely delete this policy. However, I cannot figure out how to do so. In my GCP console, I am prevented from deleting the policy because "You cannot edit org level policy." And, refreshing the Terraform state has not seemed to fix anything.

What do I need to do to delete this policy? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377969/google-cloud-platform-access-context-manager-policy-does-not-show-in-console-but) the extent of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the answer linked, you need to use the `gcloud` CLI.

```
gcloud access-context-manager policies delete POLICY_NAME
```